# how can I open an image in lightbox from a list of dropdown options after clicking the submit button

Tags: lightbox

I have been searching the web for a result all day to solve my question...

I want a list of options, that would each link to a different image. However, instead of the image opening in a new window, I want the image to open in a lightbox on the same page (lightbox evolution for wordpress is the plugin I am using).

I have tried using onclick in input field, and the lightbox will open (if class="lightbox") but no image loads.

I don't know if I need to add a function that will allow the input to recognize which option is selected so that when the input button is clicked, that that specific image opens in a lightbox.

And if I do need a function, I don't know where to add the function... onclick? Somewhere in the option tag, or select tag?

```
<form>
<select>
<option value="linkimage1.jpg">image 1</option>
<option value="linkimage2.jpg">image 2</option>
<option value="linkimage3.jpg">image 3</option>
<input type="button" value="submit" />
</select>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's to a good link that could explain how I could create a function and add it to my code, and then use a solution to call the function into my dropdown.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If using iLightBox http://ilightbox.net/ you can do that like this:

```
<select id="selectImage">
    <option>Select Image</option>
    <option value="linkimage1.jpg">image 1</option>
    <option value="linkimage2.jpg">image 2</option>
    <option value="linkimage3.jpg">image 3</option>
</select>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('select#selectImage').change(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                url = $this.val();

            $.iLightBox(url);
        });
    });
</script>
```